# Use tippyjs-react inside table cells

Tags: reactjs, react-table, tippyjs

I am trying to use [tippyjs-react](https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs-react) in table cells, but tooltips don't appear.

I added tooltip into [Cell](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options) option in [React Table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/):

```
Cell: ({ value }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tippy content="Tooltip content">
          <span>{value}</span>
        </Tippy>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-beaver-22i8r?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that inside your `Table` component you change `columns` to render a tooltip, but you do this after your `useTable` call.

So a simple fix would be to put this logic before the `useTable` call:

```
function Table({ columns, data }) {
  for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    columns[i].columns = columns[i].columns.map((column) => ({
      ...column,
      Cell: ({ value }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Tippy content="Tooltip content">
              <span>{value}</span>
            </Tippy>
          </div>
        );
      },
    }));
  }

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  });

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

[sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-kalam-6q90l)